# XSSFSheet.shiftRows error

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I want to use `shiftRows()` for an xlsx file, but I get the following error message, even though I have imported "org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaShifter;" properly

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaShifter.createForRowShift(IIII)Lorg/apache/poi/ss/formula/FormulaShifter;

The `shiftRows()` does shift the rows of my file; but after that, the program doesn't run the other commands.

Here is the code:

```
 import java.util.*;
 import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
 import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
 import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
 import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaShifter;
 import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
 import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions;
 import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTSheet;
 import org.dom4j.DocumentException;
 import java.nio.file.Files;
 import java.nio.file.*;


 XSSFWorkbook wb1;

 InputStream inp1 = new FileInputStream("/home/directory/Desktop/arx.xlsx");
 wb1 = new XSSFWorkbook(inp1);
 XSSFSheet sheet = wb1.getSheetAt(0);
 copyRow(wb1,sheet,5,2);


 FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("/home/directory/Desktop/arx.xlsx");
 wb1.write(fileOut);
 fileOut.close();

 private static void copyRow(XSSFWorkbook workbook, XSSFSheet worksheet, int sourceRowNum, int destinationRowNum) {
    // Get the source / new row
    XSSFRow newRow = worksheet.getRow(destinationRowNum);
    XSSFRow sourceRow = worksheet.getRow(sourceRowNum);

    // If the row exist in destination, push down all rows by 1 else create a new row
    if (newRow != null) {
        worksheet.shiftRows(destinationRowNum, worksheet.getLastRowNum(), 1);
    } else {
        newRow = worksheet.createRow(destinationRowNum);
    }

    // Loop through source columns to add to new row
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceRow.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
        // Grab a copy of the old/new cell
        XSSFCell oldCell = sourceRow.getCell(i);
        XSSFCell newCell = newRow.createCell(i);

        // If the old cell is null jump to next cell
        /*if (oldCell == null) {
            newCell = null;
            continue;
        }*/

        // Set the cell data value
     switch (oldCell.getCellType()) {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getStringCellValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getBooleanCellValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
            newCell.setCellErrorValue(oldCell.getErrorCellValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
            newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getNumericCellValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getRichStringCellValue());
            break;
    }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you have an older copy of an Apache POI jar on your classpath. What happens if you remove all old POI jars, leaving just the newest ones? (see also this [Apache POI FAQ entry on diagnosing this sort of problem](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006))

Comment: I only have one poi jar, it is the 3.11 version. I did what is suggested by the FAQ. I get this resault: "POI came from file:/home/directory/NetBeansProjects/poi-3.11-20141221.jar!/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/FormulaShifter.class". This is where it is supposed to come from. I have the commons-io-2.4, dom4j-2.0.0-ALPHA-2, poi-ooxml-3.9, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-beta1 and xmlbeans-5.3.0-rc1. Could one of these be causing the problem?

Comment: I tried to use the createForSheetShift method and I get a "cannot find symbol" error, but if I use org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaShifter.createForSheetShift, then I get no error.

Comment: All of your POI jars need to be from the same version. You've stated you have an unhealthy mix of 3.11, 3.9 and 3.12-beta1! Fix that to all be from the same version and you should be fine

Comment: Yep, that was the problem... Java noobs... what can you say... Thanks!

Comment: Also look out: You're copying a formula verbatim, rather than shifting the references by the distance between oldCell and newCell. This may not be what you want. `newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer...

As detailed in [this Apache POI FAQ Entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N1019C):

> **Can I mix POI jars from different versions?**
>
> No. This is not supported.
>
> All POI jars in use must come from the same version. A combination such as `poi-3.11.jar` and `poi-ooxml-3.9.jar` is not supported, and will fail to work in unpredictable ways.

You need to ensure that all your POI jars are from the same version, and then things will work fine